# Iterate over map?

Tags: apex, map

How do you iterate over a map?

```
   //Create State Abbreviation to State Count map
        map <string,decimal>    mapStates   = new map<string,decimal>();

        //Get Employee Counts for each state
        Account accStates = [Select AK__c,AL__c,.....
                             FROM Account WHERE ....];

        //Put those counts into map. 
        mapStates.put('AK', accStates.AK__c);
        //49 other states added to map. 

//Loop through map and save only states that have employees
        for (string key : mapStates.keySet()) {
            if( ?? decimal value is blank ){
                 map.removekey???            
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why dont you filter those values in the SOQL query ? I would add one thing to the solution below. I dont think it is possible to remove an item from a map while you are iterating over it.

Comment: You can remove it, here is the code for my example:          for (string key : mapStates.keySet()) {
           Decimal mapValue = mapStates.get(key);
            if(mapValue == 0){
                mapStates.remove(key);
            }
        }

Comment: Have a look into my answer, for your long term solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your pseudocode, you're iterating over the Map's keyset.

To get the corresponding value from the map, you need to call `get()` just like you normally would.

```
for(String key :myMap.keySet()){
    Decimal mapValue = myMap.get(key);
}
```

That said, it seems that you're running into a bit of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Although my solution answers your question as worded, seeing as this is your second question regarding the same general piece of code, your asking this question is a sign that you're trying to solve the underlying problem with an ill-fitting solution.

If you find yourself continuing to struggle with whatever it is you're trying to accomplish in the end, then perhaps it's time to take a step back and re-consider the data model/architecture that you're using.

Having 50 fields to hold counts of employees for each state is a red flag to me. My first instinct would be to create a junction object instead. If you'd like to go further here, you can either ask a new question (with the 'big picture' of what you're trying to accomplish), or I can start up a chat room.

Comment: Thanks @DerekF, I am just running into my normal struggle of that I don't write Apex enough on a regular basis so I forget how to accomplish certain things. I don't call myself a developer due to this fact. I try to use the declarative solutions as much as possible before I resort to Apex.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to maintain dynamic behavior, this could be an approach.

1) Create a custom metadata type which will contain `Country Initial` and `Country API` Name.

[image: Country Meta data]

2) Upload all the country initials and API name into that.

3) Now loop through the metadata values and match with the API name from `accStates` and do your processing logic.

```
//Create State Abbreviation to State Count map
Map<String, String> countryMapping = Map<String, String>();

//Get Employee Counts for each state
Account accStates = [Select AK__c,AL__c,.....
                     FROM Account WHERE ....];


for(Country_API_Mapping__mdt mdt: [SELECT CountryInitial__c, Country_API__c FROM Country_API_Mapping__mdt])
{
    //49 other states added to map. 
    countryMapping.put(mdt.CountryInitial__c, mdt.Country_API__c);
}

//Loop through map and save only states that have employees
for (String apiName : countryMapping.values()) 
{
    if(accStates.get(apiName) == null)
    {
        //do your processing
    }   
}
```